# Get the innerHTML of an element, but not the element itself

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I am working on extracting the data from a 2 column table. The first column is the variable name and the second column is the data for that variable.

I have this almost working, but some data may contain HTML and is often wrapped in a DIV. I want to get the HTML inside the DIV, but not the DIV itself. I know regex might be an solution, but I'd like to better understand DOMDocument.

This is the code I have so far:

```
private function readHtml()
{

    $url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Klpic32Gb_TDblDZDJQOkDedFGuNHAokxUXqrCPDFWE/pubhtml";

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $htmlData = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $dom        = new \DOMDocument();
    $html       = $dom->loadHTML($htmlData);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $tables     = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
    $rows       = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    $cols       = $rows->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('td');

    $table = [];
    $key = null;
    $value = null;

    foreach ($rows as $i => $row){

        //skip the heading columns
        if($i <= 1 ) continue;

        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');

        foreach ($cols as $count => $node) {

            if($count == 0) {

                $key = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_',$node->textContent));

            } else {

               $htmlNode = $node->getElementsByTagName('div');

                if($htmlNode->length >=1) {

                    $innerHTML= '';

                    foreach ($htmlNode as $innerNode) {

                        $innerHTML .= $innerNode->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $innerNode );
                    }

                    $value = $innerHTML;

                } else {

                    $value = $node->textContent;
                }
            }
        }

        $table[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $table;
}
```

My output is correct, but I'd like to not include the wrapper DIV of the data that contains HTML:

```
    Array
    (
        [type] => raw
        [direction] => north
        [intro] => Welcome to the test. 
        [html_body] => <div class="softmerge-inner" style="width: 5653px; left: -1px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut <span style="font-weight:bold;">aliquip</span> ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in <span style="text-decoration:underline;">reprehenderit</span> in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <span style="font-style:italic;">sunt in</span> culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        [count] => 1003
    )
```

**UPDATE**

Based on some feedback and ideas in the answers this is the current iteration of the function, which is slimmer and is returning the desired output. I don't feel too good about the double regex but its working.

```
private function readHtml()
{

    # the url given in your example
    $url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Klpic32Gb_TDblDZDJQOkDedFGuNHAokxUXqrCPDFWE/pubhtml";

    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $tables     = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
    $rows       = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    $cols       = $rows->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('td');

    $table = [];
    $key = null;
    $value = null;

    foreach ($rows as $i => $row){

        //skip the heading columns
        if($i <= 1 ) continue;

        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');

        foreach ($cols as $count => $node) {

            if($count == 0) {

                $key = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_',$node->textContent));

            } else {

                $value = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $node );

                $value = preg_replace('/(<div.*?>|<\/div>)/','',$value);
                $value = preg_replace('/(<td.*?>|<\/td>)/','',$value);
            }
        }

        $table[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $table;
}
```

Comment: It seems like I can cut the code down a lot by just using this:

 $value = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $node );

But I am trying to find the version of this line that doesnt include the wrapping element.

Comment: You know what, you might consider using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). See [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for manual. You have to [download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/) `simple_html_dom.php` to the directory your PHP script is in, and use <?php include 'simple_html_dom.php'; ?> to start calling functions. See my edited answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `preg_replace`! Like this:

```
$table['html_body']=preg_replace('/(<div.*?>|<\/div>)/','',$table['html_body']);
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for `preg_replace`. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#105924) for regex usage.

---

### OR! You could use [simple_html_dom.php](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/) like this:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';//<--- Must download to current directory
$url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Klpic32Gb_TDblDZDJQOkDedFGuNHAokxUXqrCPDFWE/pubhtml';
$html = file_get_html( $url );
foreach ( $html->find( "div[class=softmerge-inner]" ) as $element ) {
    echo $element->innertext;
    //See http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm for usage
}
?>
```

Comment: Your response would be more helpful if you explained how / why it resolves the problem.

Comment: Do you think this method is faster / less resource intensive that using the domdocument functions?

Comment: The latter basically does everything in your code in eight lines.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track! The next level is to learn the **very powerful** `xpath` statements, a parser like `DomDocument` offers. Consider this code example:

```
<?php
# the url given in your example    
$url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Klpic32Gb_TDblDZDJQOkDedFGuNHAokxUXqrCPDFWE/pubhtml";

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new \DOMXpath($doc);

# here comes the magic
$html_body = $xpath->query("//td[text()='html_body']")->item(0);
$div_text = $html_body->nextSibling->textContent;
echo $div_text;
?>
```

The clue is to query the `DOM` for a column which text node equals to `html_body`, this is done via `//td[here comes the expression to filter on all columns in the dom]`.  Afterwards, simply the next sibling is taken.  With this in mind, you could even rewrite your whole function with a foreach on all the rows in your `waffle` table:

```
foreach($xpath->query("//table[@class='waffle']//tr") as $row) {
    // do sth. useful here
}
```

---

For your specific example, this could be (this is somewhat shorter, isn't it?):

```
<?php
$url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Klpic32Gb_TDblDZDJQOkDedFGuNHAokxUXqrCPDFWE/pubhtml";
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new \DOMXpath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query("//table[@class='waffle']//tr") as $row) {
    $columns = $xpath->query("./td", $row);

    $key_td = $columns->item(0);
    $value_td = $columns->item(1);
    echo "[" . $key_td->nodeValue . "]: " . $value_td->nodeValue . "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Your method works, but it doesnt retain the HTML from inside the node, it just returns the text. The variable name "html_body" may change and it could be named anything.

Comment: @sterling: See the updated answer with a more general approach. `xpath` queries are very powerful and mostly more error-proof than regular expressions on `DOM` elements.

Comment: I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" on the echo line. I recall trying to use nodeValue before and it didnt return the HTML inside the node.